# How can I post a question after mistakenly posting and deleting it on another account?

Tags: support, specific-question, duplicate-questions, duplicate-accounts

I have two Stack Overflow accounts, my normal account (this one) and a work account. Yesterday, I posted a question accidentally using my work account instead of my normal one. I realized right after and deleted the question within a minute of posting it. I logged into this account to post the question, but it was prevented from posting because it was a duplicate of the previous, deleted question. I waited until today to try again, but I'm running into the same problem.

What are my options to post that question on this account? Do I need to wait a certain amount of time before I'm able to post it? Do I need to reword the question so that it's no longer flagged as a duplicate? Or is there something else I can do?

Comment: Edit your original question to remove a lot of the content, and the title, and then try again on your other account. Note, however, that deleted questions weight towards a question ban too though. Or just undelete it and have it on the account you posted it on. Does it *really* matter?

Comment: I'm not too worried about a question ban, because the work account is only (intended to be) used for my company's StackOverflow team.

In this particular case, it doesn't matter too much. I'll probably just undelete the other question if the only alternative is spend 10 minutes trying to game the duplicate detection. There are definitely questions that people would not want associated with their work account, though, so I think this information is still generally helpful.

Comment: If the question you're planning to ask is about what you should name commits in a certain circumstance, I can tell you now that you shouldn't bother trying to re-ask it on Stack Overflow under any account. It would not be on-topic here. You *might* be able to ask on [Programmers.SE]; please read their Help Center first to make sure it would be on-topic (and/or ask on their Meta site).

Comment: @CodyGray probably more accurate SE.SE meta reference would be [On the troubles of naming and terminology](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6583/31260)